# Whats wrong with if statement in shell script

Tags: shell, unix

Here is my statements:

```
print "Ss $# $2" >&3
if [ $# -eq 4 || $# -eq 3 ] && [ $2 != "d" ]
then
        print "sss"
else
        print "lol"
fi
```

The output is:

```
Ss 4 s
lol
```

Why is "sss" not being displayed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your if-condition isn't syntactically correct. You can't have `||` inside the brackets. Change it to use `-o` instead:

```
if [ $# -eq 4 -o $# -eq 3 ] && [ $2 != "d" ]
then
        print "sss"
else
        print "lol"
fi
```

Or, even better, use `[[` (if your shell supports it) which is safer and has more features. It supports `||`:

```
if [[ ( $# -eq 4 || $# -eq 3 ) && $2 != "d" ]]
then
        print "sss"
else
        print "lol"
fi
```